# How to wait to send the response of data after the forach loop is over

Tags: node.js

js
I just create a 2 function to send the response var = y but unfortunately res.end() work before then my y++ works..

This code work well with for loop without mine query
but when i used a query it working stop and it gives res like below.
Before promise call.
Loop completed.
Promise resolved: 0
Next step.
13289,
2170,
2165,
2146,
2115,
2138,
2143,
2112,
1964,
2685,
6945,
2687,
2688,
2902,
2935,
2941,
3094,
3095,
3164,
3096,

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var mysql = require('mysql');


http.createServer(function (req, res) {
var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
var end = '';
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "justcode"
});

//1. Create a new function that returns a promise
function firstFunction() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let arr = [];
        con.connect(function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            con.query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE `post_type` = 'post'", async function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                result.forEach(element => {
                    arr.push(element['ID']);
                });
                resolve(arr)
            });
        });
    })
}

//2. Create an async function
async function secondFunction() {
    //3. Await for the first function to complete
    const result = await firstFunction()
    res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
};

secondFunction()
```

}).listen(8080);

This is the working code::::

Comment: use settimeout for that
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Comment: What is `con`? You basically need to wait for `con.query`, see if it has an async or promise version instead of callback, otherwise you have to promisify it youself.

Comment: var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "",
        database: "justcode"
    });

Comment: I tried with set timeout but still not happen anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this...

```
//1. Create a new function that returns a promise
function firstFunction() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let y = 0
        con.connect(function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            con.query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE `post_type` = 'post'", async function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                result.forEach(element => {
                    console.log(element['ID']);
                    y++;
                });
                // get the results from post table
                console.log('Loop completed.')
                resolve(y); // <---- Resolve the promise here
            });
        });
        // for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        //     y++
        // }
        // console.log('Loop completed.')
        // resolve(y) // <--- Moving this inside con.query callback
    })
}

//2. Create an async function,
async function secondFunction() {
    console.log('Before promise call.')
    //3. Await for the first function to complete
    const result = await firstFunction()
    console.log('Promise resolved: ' + result)
    console.log('Next step.')
    res.end();
};

secondFunction()
```

---

Problem in The Original Question

`con.query` is an `asynchronous` execution. It accepts a callback function which then it invokes once the operation has completed. `javascript` has something called `runToCompletion` in which the execution of a function continues until the last statement.

When `secondFunction` is invoked, it further invokes(with an `await`) `firstFunction` which returns a `Promise` and the execution of the promise starts, but the caller `secondFunction` is waiting for the promise to finish.

Inside the execution of the Promise of `firstFunction`, there is a call to `con.query`, which is an `asynchronous` call, but isn't being waited for. Hence, after invoking the call to `con.query`, the javascript execution continues further... only to encounter a `resolve` after a couple of statements. A `resolve` finishes the execution of the Promise of `firstFunction` and control passes back to `secondFunction` and then execution continues from there on. Now, since the call to `con.query` will finish after sometime, and when it does, the callback function will be executed. And so we are seeing the behavior as problematic. But it's all happening as per the semantics of `javascript` execution.

Comment: Can you please explain excellently what you changes?

Comment: If it's working for you then why not!!! Let us know, then I can edit the answer with explanation and then you can accept it as answer. Is it working for you??

Comment: Thanx it's working Can you please give any doc link How resolve and promise work in js

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are using [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql), since it does not provide a promise API out of the box, you may need to promisify the `connect()` call and `query()` call yourself and `await` for them.

```
async function firstFunction() {
    
    let y = 0;

    await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        con.connect(function (err) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(); 
        });
    });
     

    let result = await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        con.query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE `post_type` = 'post'", (err, result, fields) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(result);
            // get the results from post table
        });
    });

    result.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element['ID']);
        y++;
    });
    // for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    //     y++
    // }
    console.log('Loop completed.')
    return y;
 
}
```

Alternatively, you may try using wrapper library like [mysql-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-promise) and [promise-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql)